# How to sort an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I sort an array containing objects by some property, e.g., `name`?

For example:

```
 var cart = [
     {'name': 'nokie', 'description': ''},
     {'name': 'htc', 'description': 'this is htc phone' },
     {'name': 'samsung', 'description': ''}
];
```

should be sorted to:

```
 var cart = [  
     {'name': 'htc', 'description': 'this is htc phone' },
     {'name': 'nokie', 'description': ''},
     {'name': 'samsung', 'description': ''}
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript built in function sort

example:

```
cart.sort(function(a, b){return a.name > b.name})
```

This will sort it by name. It is actually Array built in function. I You have just numbers You do not have to put function inside but for arrays of objects You should. Inside of function You can make Your own compare rules.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to compare `name` property with [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method:

```
cart.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.name.localeCompare(a.name);
});
```

Comment: When editing the OP I assumed they wanted to sort by `name`. Sorting by description would be just as valid given the example. Either way, it's a minor difference.